# Prevent submission of form for non numeric fields

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up a form validation - this works - but only for odd numbers, if you enter an even number, e.g. part number TEST and quantity 2 then the alert will come up, if you enter qty 3 then the form will submit. Any ideas ?

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function allnumeric(inputtxt)
   {
      var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
      if(form2.qty.value.match(numbers) & (form2.product.value != ""))
      {
      return true;
      }
      else
      {
      alert('Please input numeric characters only or fill in the product field')
      {
      return false;
      }
   }  
   }
</script>
```

Form

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="booking-printlabel2.asp?insert=yes" onsubmit="return allnumeric()">


                <input name="product" type="text" id="product" style="height:55px;font-size:30pt;" size="10"/>


                <input name="qty" type="text" id="qty" style="height:55px;font-size:30pt;" size="3"/>


          <input type="submit" name="Print Labels2" id="Print Labels2" value="Print Labels" style="height:55px;font-size:30pt;"/>

    </form>
```

Thanks all - it was the typo,    `if(form2.qty.value.match(numbers) & (form2.product.value != "")) changed to    if(form2.qty.value.match(numbers) && (form2.product.value != ""))` and it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're targeting html5:

```
<input name="qty" type="number" id="qty" style="height:55px;font-size:30pt;"/>
```

Or if you really want to have type="text":

```
<input name="qty" type="text" id="qty" pattern="\d+" style="height:55px;font-size:30pt;"/>
```

Also, you've got a typo:

```
if(form2.qty.value.match(numbers) & (form2.product.value != ""))
```

should be

```
if(form2.qty.value.match(numbers) && (form2.product.value != ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your if condition you have to add one more if condition to check the odd and even number. You have to do this:

```
if(form2.qty.value.match(numbers) & (form2.product.value != ""))
{
    var num = form2.qty.value;
    if(num%2 == 0) { 
        alert('Even number'); 
    } else {       
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function allnumeric(inputtxt)
  {
      var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
      var qty = form2.qty.value;
      if(qty.match(numbers) && (form2.product.value != ""))
      {
        if(qty & 1) // even number
          return true;
        else
          alert('Even number');
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Please input numeric characters only or fill in the product field')
        return false;
      }  
 }
```

```html
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="booking-printlabel2.asp?insert=yes" onsubmit="return allnumeric()">


                <input name="product" type="text" id="product" style="height:55px;font-size:30pt;" size="10"/>


                <input name="qty" type="text" id="qty" style="height:55px;font-size:30pt;" size="3"/>


          <input type="submit" name="Print Labels2" id="Print Labels2" value="Print Labels" style="height:55px;font-size:30pt;"/>

    </form>
```